# Finding the minimum integer after entering a series of numbers in a loop

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

Hi Everyone can someone tell me how can I find the minimum integer for a series of integers in a loop?
I'm using a scanner class to get the input from the user and I implemented a do-while loop since the loop is terminated when the input is 0. then the program outputs the result.

my code so far in the loop is like this

```
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice = 0;
    int sumPositive = 0;
    int sumOdd = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int min=99999999;
    do {
        choice = console.nextInt();
        if (choice < min) {
            min = choice;
            } // setting the minimum number
        if (choice > 0) {
            sumPositive += choice;
            count++;
        } // positive numbers sum and count
        if (choice % 2 == 1 && choice > 0) {
            sumOdd += choice;
        } // odd numbers sum

    } while ( choice != 0);
```

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I can't figure out the code to find the minimum integer without the stupid initializing that I had

Answer (score 0):

Use *if (choice < min&&choice!=0)* rather than *if (choice < min)*
as when choice == 0 then your min becomes 0.

Comment: where should I initialize the new min and what value should I give it?

Comment: Also, negative numbers can be used as a minimum value so will the same code work on them?

Comment: What do you mean by new min to initialize???
For handling negative numbers you can use choice!=0.

Comment: Use int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;  for initialize min.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
public int findLowestNumberInSeries() {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    int lowest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int input;
    do {
        input = console.nextInt();
        if (input < lowest) {
            lowest = input;
        }
    }
    while (input != 0);
    return lowest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is **change** the `int min = 99999999` to `int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE` and **print** the value of `min` at the end. Cheers.